# How to extract a subset based on value by grepl

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi i want to extract all the observations starting from "120.5" I am doing it in following way.

```
a<-c(120.1,120.3,120.5,120.566)
Part<-c(1,2,3,4)
DFFF<-data.frame(a,Part)
lill <- subset(DFFF, grepl('^120.5', a), select = Part)
> lill
  Part
3    3
```

I want outcome to be 3 and 4. How to do that in R.

Comment: Can do: `DFFF[DFFF$a>=120.5,"Part"]` or use `DFFF[grep('120.5',DFFF$a),"Part"]`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're only subsetting on a numerical variable, @NelsonGon's solution `DFFF[DFFF$a>=120.5,]`is absolutely the first option. If, for some reason, you **have** to use `grepl`you can subset like this:

```
DFFF[grepl("120.5", DFFF$a), ]
        a Part
3 120.500    3
4 120.566    4
```

But bear in mind that this only works as long as the numbers in `a` are **not** equal to or greater than `120.6`; all these values will not be matched.

Answer (score 1):

In base R

```
ind <- which(DFFF$a >= 120.5)
lill <- DFFF$Part[ind]
```

Tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
DFFF %>%
  filter(a >= 120.5) %>%
  pull(Part)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, quotes needed.

```
lill <- subset(DFFF, grepl('^120.5', a), select="Part")
lill
#   Part
# 3    3
# 4    4
```